# Create list of all sheet names in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that creates a new sheet in the workbook and lists all the sheet names in a column, which work fine but I would like it to leave 27 empty rows between each sheet name

```
Dim xWs As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xTitleId = "All Sheet Names"

Application.Sheets(xTitleId).Delete

Application.Sheets.Add.index

Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet

xWs.Name = xTitleId

For i = 2 To Application.Sheets.Count
    xWs.Range("A" & (i - 1)) = Application.Sheets(i).Name
Next
```

Example this is how it lists them now
[image]

And this is how i want it to list them with the empty spaces in between each sheet name
[image]

Comment: Try doing `xWs.Range("A" & (i - 1)).Offset(27,0) = Application.Sheets(i).Name`

Comment: It just moved the list down to row 27 :(

Comment: `xWs.Range("A" & ((i-2) * 27) +1)`

Comment: What @ScottCraner wrote. Also, that `On Error Resume Next` will bite you in the ass later. Don't do that, use some other way to avoid error when trying to delete a non-existing sheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner `code xWs.Range("A" & ((i - 2) * 27) + 1) = Application.Sheets(i).Name ` This worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP said 27 blank rows between them, so the next row will be 28 rows down.

[image]

```
For i = 2 To Application.Sheets.Count

    xWs.Range("A" & ((i - 1) * 28) - 27) = Application.Sheets(i).Name

Next
```